# Using Iron Router on Server Side of Meteor Application?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, iron-router

I tried calling Router.go('confirmation') to take the user to confirmation page once the information has been inserted into the database.

```
Meteor.methods({
    'createNewItinerary': function(itinerary){
      var userId = Meteor.userId();
      ItineraryList.insert({
        [....values.....]
      },function(){
        Router.go('confirmation'); 
      });

    }
```

In the server console, I get the response: `has no method 'go'`
[image]

The data is inserted successfully, so how do I get it to route to a confirmation page?

-- Edit --

Will this work? It seems to but don't know how to verify:

```
Meteor.call('createNewItinerary',itinerary, function(err, data){
       if(err){
         console.log(err);
       }
       else Router.go('confirmation');
     });
```

Comment: If insert didnt return any errors go to confirmation page

Comment: Will this work?

`Meteor.call('createNewItinerary',itinerary, function(err, data){
       if(err){
         console.log(err);
       }
       Router.go('confirmation');
     });`

Comment: router.go should be wothin 'else' block

Comment: edited to put Router.go in else block! thank you @yoK0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your suggestion is the good choice to make.
You can't catch the Router in a Meteor method because it's server side. You have to do it in the **callback function**, exactly like you suggested :

```
Meteor.call('createNewItinerary',itinerary, function(err, data){
   if(err){
     console.log(err);
   }
   Router.go('confirmation');
 });
```

To check that the work has correctly been done on the server, just throw errors, for example:

```
 throw new Meteor.Error( 500, 'There was an error processing your request' );
```

Then if error is thrown, it will be logged in your client side.

Hope it helps you :)

Answer (score 1):

Your suggestion makes sense to me:

```
Meteor.call('createNewItinerary',itinerary, function(err, data){
   if(err){
     console.log(err);
   }
   Router.go('confirmation');
 });
```

You'll call createNewItinerary and when it returns you'll send the user to the confirmation page. That said, you might want some error checking - as you've got it currently you send the user to the confirmation page regardless of a successful or failed insert. Perhaps:

```
Meteor.call('createNewItinerary',itinerary, function(err, data){
   if(err){
     console.log(err);
     Router.go('errorpage'); // Presuming you have a route setup with this name
   }
   else Router.go('confirmation');
 });
```